# How can I get NextJS to display CSS errors?

Tags: typescript, next.js

In the context of my work I have a NextJS website I need to extend / fix.

In the already existing code there is many, many CSS classes and I noted that some of them do not exist at all.

Here is a simplified example :

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import Image from 'next/image'
import styles from '/styles/Questionnaire.module.css'
import { Container, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap"; 


const Questionnaire: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.I_do_not_exist}>
        <Container>
           ...
        </Container>
    </div>
)}

export default Questionnaire
```

Here I did a `I_do_not_exist` CSS class that is not present in any of the CSS files. In the inspector I noticed that theses divs do not have any CSS classes attached and the console does not show anything, just the compiling / compiled text output

Is there a way top trigger an error or have any kind of warning to indicate that the CSS class was not found ?

Currently I need to go div by div in the inspector to find the ones that do not have any CSS attached or find the div that does not seem to react when I attempt to change it's CSS. This is tedious to say the least and it's going to be too much work for a big code base

Comment: https://github.com/Quramy/typed-css-modules

Comment: Thank you for your help but I am a bit confused as to how this can help me in my situation ?

Comment: Your `styles` is currently probably of type `any` or `Record<string, string>`. By using that package you can generate type definitions for your `.module.css` files. Then, the typescript compiler should throw an error on accessing a non-existent property on `styles`.

Comment: oh thx. I will give it a try. I just need to be careful of what packages I install ( not my project ). Would you know of an option / setting / parameter that would allow me to get those errors in NextJS without resorting to the installation of a package ?